# How to allow googlebot to crawl publically visible pages on my django site that are behind login?

Tags: python, django, authentication, web-crawler, googlebot

I've found several posts about this but can't seem to get a straight answer for my case.

I'm using django allauth to make users sign up before posting anything. However, all the pages are visible to the public and don't require login to view.

How do I allow google to crawl the pages without having to go through the login?

Would a simple sitemap work?

I looked into first click free but from what I read it only crawls the first page after the login? Or should I whitelist the IP's?

Any direction would be great, thanks.